# Editing Groovy components in Mule (Anypoint) Studio?

Tags: groovy, mule, mule-studio

Recently upgraded from an older Mule Studio to the latest Anypoint Studio and am having a problem editing existing inline Groovy components.

I can display the message flow and can see the component, and the bottom pane  shows "Script Text" with ten lines of script code displayed - problem is, this particular script is a few hundred lines long, and editing it 10 lines at a time is quite cumbersome.

The older version would let me re-size the window so I could see and edit as many lines as I could fit on my display...is there a way to do this in the newer product? If not, what would be the recommended way to edit large Groovy components? If the build-in editor can't do this, is there a way to launch an external editor (maybe Intelli-J?) when I select an inline Groovy script component?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a method to re-size the window in Anypoint, but you certainly can edit the inline script within the Configuration XML tab.

My preferred method is to put the script in a separate file. You can edit in its own tab. Have the Groovy component call the file. An example would be:

```
        <!-- delete each file -->
        <scripting:component doc:name="Delete Each File Script">
            <scripting:script 
                engine="Groovy" 
                file="deleteEachFileFromPayload.groovy"/>
        </scripting:component>
```

The Groovy script file would just need to be located in the *main/resources* folder of the application.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...certainly for new stuff, we're splitting scripts into separate files. Problem is we have a large number of pre-existing inline scripts and some very long Mule flows with many inline scripts, so editing in the Configuration XML tab isn't practical - you can easily get "lost" and change unintended things. The older releases (3.4?) behaved perfectly, resizing the editor to whatever number of lines you want - too bad this behavior was lost in Anypoint.

Answer (score 0):

In groovy properties you can find script file and script reference you can user this to add the groovy script files.